# C fscanf jump values

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

I'm trying to make a program to read the values ​​in a file and prints them on the screen, now in part to print the files that my program ends up skipping some values​​. Another question, how would I do to allocate memory dynamically for v in this case?

file:

```
3 -1 1 3 1 
2 2 1 -3.4 
5 -1 -2 5 0 -3 1
```

code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 100

int main(){
float *v;
int i=0;

v=(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("entrada.txt","rt");
if (fp == NULL) {
printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!\n");
exit(1); }

do{
fscanf(fp," %f",&v[i]);
printf("v[%d] = [%f]\n",i,v[i]);
i++;
}
while ((fscanf(fp," %f",&v[i])) != EOF);

int fclose (FILE* fp);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

result:

```
v[0] = [3.00000]
v[1] = [1.00000]
v[2] = [1.00000]
v[3] = [2.00000]
v[4] = [-3.00000]
v[5] = [-1.00000]
v[6] = [5.00000]
v[7] = [-3.00000]
v[8] = [1.00000]
```

Comment: do-while --> while. Conditions and internally twice read is performed.

Comment: look at `realloc` for dynamic re sizing of `v`

Comment: `int fclose (FILE* fp);` --> `fclose (fp);`

Comment: about the realloc, i tried v=(float*)realloc(v,i*sizeof(float)); in while but doesn't work

Comment: @Eraldo Probably `i` -> `(i+1)`. or The extension at full size of allocated memory. `v=malloc((size=100)*sizeof(float));`.. `if(i==size) v= realloc(v, (size+=100)*sizeof(float));`

Comment: when performing a realloc() be sure to save the previous value in 'v', just in case the realloc() fails, so the previously allocated memory can be passed to free() at the end of main()

Comment: since 'v' is initially set via a call to malloc() there needs to be a call to free(), passing 'v' as the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
while ((fscanf(fp," %f",&v[i])) != EOF){
    printf("v[%d] = [%f]\n",i,v[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two file reads in an iteration, change the condition in while from:

```
while ((fscanf(fp," %f",&v[i])) != EOF);
```

to:

```
while(!feof(fp));
```

This should prevent the value skipping problem. Hope this helps.